# Featured Images in Modified Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

So I have this modified Wordpress Loop. The [Wordpress Modified/Super Loop](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently/) is tasked to assigned a unique HTML structure for each post.

Anyway, I successfully used it. Not until I added the codes that calls the featured image and make it a background-image (css style property).

What the error I'm encountering right now is that it pulls the same Featured image for all post. Example, for post number two to six, **it display the same featured image** that belongs to Post #2.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count >= 2 && $count <= 6) : ?> 



//code to pull the featured images' urls

    <?php
    global $post;

    if (has_post_thumbnail()) { //if a thumbnail has been set
    $imgID = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID); //get the id of the featured image
    $featuredImage1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'TypeTwo-1' );//get the url of the featured image (returns an array)
    $featuredImage2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'TypeThree-2' );//get the url of the featured image (returns an array)

    $posttypetwoURL1 = $featuredImage1[0]; //get the url of the image out of the array
    $posttypetwoURL2 = $featuredImage2[0]; //get the url of the image out of the array
    ?>


    <style type="text/css">

    .pt2s-img {
    border:none;
    color:black;
    background-image: url(<?php echo $posttypetwoURL1 ?>);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:484px;
    height:350px;
    display:inline-block;
    }   

    @media screen and (max-width:1231px) {
        .pt2s-img {
        border:none;
        color:black;
        background-image: url(<?php echo $posttypetwoURL2 ?>);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:484px;
        height:350px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:800px) {
        .pt2s-img {
        border:none;
        color:black;
        background-image: url(<?php echo $imgURL3 ?>);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:150px;
        height:250px;
        }
    }

    </style>

    <?php
    }//end if

    ?>

    <a class="pt2s-img" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" >
    </a>

//code to pull the featured images' urls    


<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I suspect that this codes is messing the loop:

```
 $imgID = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID); //get the id of the featured image
    $featuredImage1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'TypeTwo-1' );//get the url of the featured image (returns an array)
    $featuredImage2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'TypeThree-2' );//get the url of the featured image (returns an array)

    $posttypetwoURL1 = $featuredImage1[0]; //get the url of the image out of the array
    $posttypetwoURL2 = $featuredImage2[0]; //get the url of the image out of the array
```

But i am unsure. I think that those codes should be put somewhere so it will not mess with the loop and display the correct images.

Any advice on correctly doing it?

Answer (score 0):

`has_post_thumbnail()` accepts post ID as its argument, use `has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)` instead. Because you are using modified loop, you need to implicitly pass post ID as function argument.

Comment: Tried this but nothing is happening.

Comment: actually, it works using in <img> tag, but the problem is the image should go as a background image. This way, I can call what size I want.

Comment: Could you open the webpage in a web browser and see the HTML source code? How many `<style type="text/css">` [...] have you got there? It seems like you are using CSS style declaration within the loop and it gets repeated multiple times.

Comment: I can see one <style type="text/css"> tag in my browser.

Comment: If it works with <img> tak then it's a problem with your CSS markup. the simplest way would be using an inline style such as this: `<a class="pt2s-img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $posttypetwoURL1 ?>);" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" >`

Comment: I understand. What you essentially need here is a change from a CSS CLASS to an ID. You should put everything that is common in a class, and what is unique in an id. `<style>.pt2s-img { 
    border:none;
    color:black;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:484px;
    height:350px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
    
#bgimage<?php echo ++$i; ?> {
background-image: url(<?php echo $posttypetwoURL1 ?>);
}
</style>
<a class="pt2s-img" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" >`

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't be sure right now, my guess would be that by getting the id with the `global $post;`, you get the ID of the first post.

Since you're in the loop, you could solve this by using the following function:
`get_the_ID();`
(see the [WordPress Function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID))

That would give you the following way of getting the image ID:

```
 $imgID = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); //get the id of the featured image
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I changed it but nothing happened. It pulls the incorrect featured image.